# Cannot find module 'copy-webpack-plugin'

Tags: react-scripts

I'm upgraded the react-scripts package to 5.0.0. After the upgrade, i ran npm start command and application is broken and getting below error

> [webpack-cli] Failed to load 'D:\web\config\webpack.uat.js' config
> [webpack-cli] Error: Cannot find module 'copy-webpack-plugin' Require
> stack:
>
> - D:\web\config\webpack.common.js
> - D:\web\config\webpack.uat.js
> - D:\web\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\webpack-cli.js
> - D:\web\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\bootstrap.js
> - D:\web\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js
> - D:\web\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js
>   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
>   at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
>   at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
>   at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:101:18)
>   at Object. (D:\web\config\webpack.common.js:2:27)
>   at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
>   at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
>   at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
>   at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
>   at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19) {   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',   requireStack: [
>   'D:\web\config\webpack.common.js',
>   'D:\web\config\webpack.uat.js',
>   'D:\web\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\webpack-cli.js',
>   'D:\web\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\bootstrap.js',
>   'D:\web\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js',
>   'D:\web\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js'
>   ] } npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 2 npm ERR!
>   web@0.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server --progress --config config/webpack.uat.js` npm ERR! Exit status 2 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed
>   at the web@0.0.0 start script. npm ERR! This is probably not a
>   problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

*installed "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2" and "@webpack-cli/serve": "^1.6.1" too*

below is webpack.uat.js file

```
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

const common = require('./webpack.common');
const srcDirectory = path.resolve(__dirname, '../src');

module.exports = merge(common, {

  entry: {
    main: ['react-hot-loader/patch', path.join(srcDirectory, 'main.js')]
  },

  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'react-dom': '@hot-loader/react-dom'
    }
  },

  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
  },

  mode: 'development',

  devtool: 'eval-source-map',

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        // exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'resolve-url-loader',
          {loader: 'sass-loader', options: {sourceMap: true}}
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        // exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      }
    ]
  },

  devServer: {
    contentBase: srcDirectory,
    hot: true,
    port: 9000,
    historyApiFallback: {
      disableDotRule: true
    },
    stats: 'minimal',
    overlay: true,
    proxy: {
      '/api/**': {
        target: {
          port: 8080
        },
        secure: false
      },
      '/actuator/**': {
        target: {
          port: 8080
        },
        secure: false
      }
    }
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new Dotenv({
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../.env.uat')
    })
  ]

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to:
npm install copy-webpack-plugin --save-dev

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).